# Contacts have been randomly merged

Tags: contacts

I own Moto G4 plus, I have seen from a week that my contacts getting randomly merged to another contact..I was shocked to see this.

Answer (score 0):

If you previously made a contacts backup, you can proceed to delete all the "corrupted contacts", then restore your backup.

Finally use [Duplicate Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accaci&hl=en) to remove any newly created duplicates. The tools serves its purpose well. I have had the same problem. Hope it helps